# Is there a way to judge which article is natural or not?

Tags: nlp

When designing a search engine, I think we need to have an algorithm that can distinguish between garbage and normal documents. Otherwise, the garbage document may appear in the top search results and the quality of the search results may not good.

It may be an ambiguous question, but is there a way to judge which article is natural or not? Articles like Lorem Ipsum are definitely unnatural. Also, it is unnatural to write words that are randomly drawn from human writings. (Eg. Also it write but there an be it is may.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no certain and accurate way to filter natural and unnatural articles. But there can be the idea if you have a big data warehouse as that of google.Google is already working on the project to maximise
the relevant search patterns for natural articles.

Check out the below link which could clear your problem to an extent
https://www.ieee.org/publications_standards/publications/rights/ID_Plagiarism.html
ANd this research paper might also help
http://trec.nist.gov/pubs/trec16/papers/ursinus.legal.final.pdf
Hope this helps....